# window.array; change value more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a game and here is the basic functions I have to help understand.

I have a `window.currentLevel = 0;` at the top for some reason a regular var does not work. And then I have these three buttons, `$('#level1')` `$('#level2')` and `$('#level3')` .What supposed to happen is when you click, for instance `$('#level1').click()` it will set the current level to `currentLevel = 1;`

I have the same method for 2, and 3. The problem is that it kind of ignores the second and third button.

I tested and messed around For the `$('#level1')` button click i changed the `currentLevel` to 2 or 3 and it played the level correctly, so and example is lets say the first button is set to `currentLevel = 1`, It would play level 1 once you beat it and click button 2 it would play level 1 again, I know it is, because I guess the `currentLevel` won't change again?

And i always get this console error called `"error: currentLevel is not defined;"` or something like that. Here is the code of the whole thing I was explaining.

```
 window.currentLevel = 0;
    $('#level1').click(function () {
 currentLevel = 1;
        $("#mainMenu").hide();
        $('#startLevel1').show();


    });
    $('#level2').click(function () {
 currentLevel = 2;
        $("#mainMenu").hide();
        $('#startLevel1').show();
    });
    $('#level3').click(function () {
 currentLevel = 3;
        $('#mainMenu').hide();
        $('#startLevel1').show();

    });
```

Comment: You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: `userLevel` is not in the shown code

Comment: ohh that was my fault when typing it.

Answer (score 0):

You declare window.currentLevel, which is a property on the window object, but then when you set it in later functions you're just setting currentLevel. This implicitly creates a new variable called currentLevel that only has scope within that function.

Use window.currentLevel whenever you refer to it.

Comment: *"This implicitly creates a new variable called currentLevel that only has scope within that function."* um, no it does not...

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this?